# Get FK set for each instance in queryset

Tags: python, django

I have a tree-like Django model say named A, which been done by django-mptt.

```
class A(MPTTModel):
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self')
```

this class automaticly has the 'children' manager, so i can easily get the subtree

There is another model, which have FK link to A:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    link_to_a = models.ForeignKey(A)
```

I know, that if i want to get SomeModel set of A instance i can do that:

```
a = A.objects.filter(blah)
a.somemodel_set.all()
```

and the question is:
what is the most pythonic way to fetch somemodel_set of each instance in some queryset under A model, i.e. i want 4 example this:

```
some_A_instance.children.all().get_all_somemodel_instances()
```

and get_all_somemodel_instances() should retrieve ziped queryset of sets for each children

Answer (score 1):

Do you just need the related items in one list, or do you need to associate each set with their parent? If the former, you can get them all at once with this:

```
related_items = SomeModel.objects.filter(link_to_a=some_A_instance.children.all())
```

which will do one single query (with a subquery) to get everything.

Otherwise, you can use [`prefetch_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to get all items' related sets in one go:

```
items = some_A_instance.children.all().prefetch_related('somemodel_set')
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
[child.somemodel_set.all() for child in some_A_instance.children.all()]
```

Comment: Output of this is list, I need lazy object like QuerySet

Comment: The output is a list of QuerySet objects.